# Space have created after using regex for foloat number in python

Tags: python, regex

I am using a regex pattern to add QtyOrd before a number if it contains any quantity identifier. My code is working its the quantity is an integer. But for float number after using regex it creates a space after the first number. For e.g. 1.00 converted to 1 .00. it should not have an space

```
def process_qty_text(text):
    text = re.sub(
            r'(?i)(\s*)[-:;.+=#*]*(qty to order|qty required|qty reqd|qty|quantity requested|pza|quantity|q-ty|q\'ty|pcs)\s*[-\.\*#:=]*\s*(\d+)',
            r' \1 QtyOrd \3 ', text)
    return text

text ='''   
    
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT Pza 1.00

75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT Quantity 1.00

'''

print(process_qty_text(text))
```

The out is coming as............

```
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT   QtyOrd 1 .00 
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT   QtyOrd 1 .00
```

but it should be.....

```
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT   QtyOrd 1.00 
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT   QtyOrd 1.00
```

**Update**

but it should be.....

```
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT QtyOrd 1
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT QtyOrd 1
```

Comment: Do you want to say there must be three spaces between `LEFT` and `QtyOrd`?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew. It should be like this. I just update the outcome

75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT QtyOrd 1
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT QtyOrd 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```py
import re

def process_qty_text(text):
    text = re.sub(
            r'(?i)\s*[-:;.+=#*]*(?:qty to order|qty required|qty reqd|qty|quantity requested|pza|quantity|q-ty|q\'ty|pcs)\s*[-\.\*#:=]*\s*(\d+)(?:\.0+\b)?',
            r' QtyOrd \1', text)
    return text

text ='''75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT Pza 1.00
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT Quantity 1.00
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT qty 1345.456'''

print(process_qty_text(text))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/Sd8czW). Output:

```py
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT QtyOrd 1
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT QtyOrd 1
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT QtyOrd 1345.456
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JkeOdi/2).

*Details*:

- `(?i)` - case insensitive modifier
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `[-:;.+=#*]*` - zero or more punctuation chars from the set
- `(?:qty to order|qty required|qty reqd|qty|quantity requested|pza|quantity|q-ty|q\'ty|pcs)` - several hard-coded alternatives
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `[-\.\*#:=]*` - zero or more punctuations from the set
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(\d+)` - one or more digits
- `(?:\.0+\b)?` - an optional `.` + one or more `0`s followed with a word boundary.

Comment: ..Thanks for your reply.. Just need only integer value. e.g 1345.456 should be 1345

Comment: @SafayetKarim Fixed. I replaced `0+` with `\d+`.

Comment: Thank you.. Now its fine :)

Comment: @ Wiktor Stribiżew.. after thinking last night I think your first code is a better solution for me. because any number after decimal should not be truncated as it will not lose any accurate information. So, I revert back to your previous code. Thanks a lot..

Comment: just need a small help.. I am trying your regex in another function that also do the same but will add units identifier after the quantity.

'text = re.sub(r'(?i)(\s*)(\d+)(?:\.0+\b)?\s*[-:;.+=#*]*(?:pcs|pc|off|units|unit|of|each|ea.|ea|pieces|pza|full sets|sets|nos|set|e.a.|e.a|nr)', r' \1 \2 units  ', text)'

input text is 

75925 75925 SSW40 3.555 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT 1.00 pza
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT 1345.456 pza

output will be

Just one thing I don't need to change the middle floating number (3.55)

Comment: @SafayetKarim You can use [this regex solution](https://regex101.com/r/7lJhlF/2), see  the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XD7QpV).

Comment: This one working fine.. Thank you your help

Answer (score 2):

Remove spaces after `\3` in `r' \1 QtyOrd \3 '`

```
def process_qty_text(text):
    text = re.sub(
            r'(?i)(\s*)[-:;.+=#*]*(qty to order|qty required|qty reqd|qty|quantity requested|pza|quantity|q-ty|q\'ty|pcs)\s*[-\.\*#:=]*\s*(\d+)',
            r'\1 QtyOrd \3', text)
    return text

text ='''   
    
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT Pza 1.00

75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT Quantity 1.00

'''

print(process_qty_text(text))
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you are parsing the float number with a wrong regex.  You can modify your regex and codes as follows;

```
def process_qty_text(text):
    text = re.sub(
            r'(?i)(\s*)[-:;.+=#*]*(qty to order|qty required|qty reqd|qty|quantity requested|pza|quantity|q-ty|q\'ty|pcs)\s*[-\.\*#:=]*\s*(\d+(?:.\d+)?)',
            r'\1QtyOrd \3', text)
    return text

text ='''   
    
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT Pza 1.00

75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT Quantity 1.00

'''

print(process_qty_text(text))
```

Output:

```
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT QtyOrd 1.00

75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT QtyOrd 1.00
```

The number (integer or float) should be parsed with regex `(\d+(?:.\d+)?)`.  Your current regex `(\d+)` is parsing only the integral part.  That is, `\3` returns only `1` and the fractional part has a space between the integral part because you placed a space after `\3` as `\3` .

### Edit

To extract only the integral part discarding the fractional part, you can amend the code as follows:

```
def process_qty_text(text):
    text = re.sub(
            r'(?i)(\s*)[-:;.+=#*]*(qty to order|qty required|qty reqd|qty|quantity requested|pza|quantity|q-ty|q\'ty|pcs)\s*[-\.\*#:=]*\s*(\d+)(?:.\d+)?',
            r'\1QtyOrd \3', text)
    return text

text ='''   
    
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT Pza 1.00

75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT Quantity 1.00

'''

print(process_qty_text(text))
```

Output:

```
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT QtyOrd 1

75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT QtyOrd 1
```

Comment: @SeanBean.. I just update the outcome. Can we remove .00 while using re.sub to add QtyOrd before quantity. Actually, I am facing an issue still for the floating number. Better to use an integer number. Thanks in advanced

75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT QtyOrd 1 
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT QtyOrd 1

Comment: @SafayetKarim  See my edit above, discarding the fractional part in the extraction.

Answer (score 2):

You need only 2 capture group. Use it like this:

```
text = re.sub(
       r'(?i)\s*[-:;.+=#*]*(qty to order|qty required|qty reqd|qty|quantity requested|pza|quantity|q-ty|q\'ty|pcs)\s*[-.*#:=]*\s*(\d+)\.?\d*',
       r' \1 QtyOrd \2', text)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jkwAQE/5)

Comment: I just update the outcome. Can we remove .00 while using re.sub to add QtyOrd before quantity. Actually, I am facing an issue still for the floating number. Better to use an integer number. Thanks in advanced

75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT QtyOrd 1 
75925 75925 SSW40 HOSE ASSY MOTOR-LEFT QtyOrd 1

Comment: please update sample input and expected output in your question

Comment: the code above link is not working for me

Comment: Clarify what is now working. https://regex101.com/r/jkwAQE/5 shows replaced text under SUBSTITUTION area

Comment: "(?i)\s*[-:;.+=#*]*(qty to order|qty required|qty reqd|qty|quantity requested|pza|quantity|q-ty|q\'ty|pcs)\s*[-.*#:=]*\s*(\d+)\.?\d*"gm 

- I just copy this from your code and getting this below error
error: invalid group reference 3 at position 11

Are you using Python 2.7 or 3?

Comment: In my code I only have `\1` or `\2` but there is no `\3`